# Can $\{(1,2,0),(2,0,3)\}$ span $U=\{(r,s,0) \mid r,s, \in \mathbb{R}\}?$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is it possible that $\{(1,2,0),(2,0,3)\}$ can span the subspace $U=\{(r,s,0) \mid r,s, \in \mathbb{R}\}?$

Using the definition of span, I have gotten this far:

$a(1,2,0)+b(2,0,3)=(r,s,0)$ (where $a,b,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$)

This gives the following set of equations:

$a+2b=r, 2a=s, 3b=0$

I am not sure how to proceed- a hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your set of equations is good. Keep solving them. What does $3b=0$ tell you?

Comment: It means $b=0$, so $a=r$?

Comment: sure the answer is no, it can't!

Comment: @Sujaan: Okay, and if you substitute that into the remaining equation involving $s$...

Comment: It means $2r=s \implies r=\dfrac{s}{2}.$ So this means that $a=\dfrac{s}{2}$ is the only thing that would work for $a$, so since $a$ can't be any number, $U$ cannot be spanned by the set?

Comment: Pretty much! That's not quite how I would put it though. It's not that there's a constraint on $a$; the issue is that there are two conflicting constraints on $a$. It's easier to phrase the result in terms of $r$ and $s$. You've shown that if a vector $(r,s,0)$ lies in the span of $\{(1,2,0),(2,0,3)\}$, then $2r=s$. So if we take a vector where $2r\neq s$, such as $(1,1,0)$, then it doesn't lie in the span!

Comment: @ChrisCulter: Thanks, makes more sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the obtained equations $a=r=s/2$, so if $r\ne s/2$ you cannot chose $a$.

Answer (score 4):

Begin by noting that $b(2,0,3)$ will only match $(r,s,0)$ if $b=0$.

Answer (score 4):

The span of these two vectors is (at most) two-dimensional. As the second vector has a nonzero third component, it is not in the (also two-dimensional) space $U$, at most a one-dimensional subspace of the span is in $U$ and hence cannot be all of $U$.